# Getting index sectors historical weightings from Bloomberg

Tags: equities, index

I want to know how to download an index sectors' historical weightings from Bloomberg.

For example, S&P 500 is comprised of Telecom Svc, Materials, Utilities, Energy, Consumer Staples, Industrials, Consumer Discretionary, Financials, Health Care, and Information Tech.

Is there a way to obtain their historical weights from date 1 to date 2?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the function "SPX Index MEMB" on a Bloomberg terminal. It shows the constituents of the S&P 500.

There should be a tab called "Historical Summary". That tab shows a chart of the sector weighting over time by default.

Comment: where can I find the function on the Bloomberg terminal?

Comment: Just open a terminal and type "SPX Index MEMB", and then press enter.

Comment: I see. This is great. Thank you very much. I am also interested in Samsung Electronic's historical weight of KOSPI 200 (korean stock exchange). How do I do it?